# How to escape new line while working with REGEX

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have written this regex to extract only 2 or 3 words name

```
([A-Z]{1}[a-z]+\s[A-Z]{1}[a-z]+\s[A-Z]{1}[a-z]+)|([A-Z]{1}[a-z]+\s[A-Z]{1}[a-z]+)
```

Eg. the output should be just `"Saurabh Biawai"` but instead it's giving me this `"Saurabh Biawal\nWey"` from below text

```
Saurabh Biawai
Wey anna/ DOB: 10/12/1994
```

Comment: What does the actual code look like? Can you provide a [mcve]? We can't debug code we can't see.

Answer (score 1):

So the class `\s` matches whitespace characters, including newlines.  You could replace this with `[^\n\S]`, meaning anything but newlines and non-whitespace characters.

You don't actually need the groups in your expression, as the `|` will act on the whole expression to the left or right anyway.  Also the `{1}`s are unnecessary, as the default is exactly one match.

The regex `[A-Z][a-z]+[^\n\S][A-Z][a-z]+[^\n\S][A-Z][a-z]+|[A-Z][a-z]+[^\n\S][A-Z][a-z]+` returns `'Saurabh Biawai'`